# All screen compatibility screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm designing an android activity which I want it can be compatible with all screens resolutions. Right now, I did it knowing that the screen will have 1024x600pixels, and in the layout_weidth and height, I used absolute pixels... (I started with dp's but it doesn't work in my mobile, but it works in the emulator... very confusing, so I decided to try with pixels and they worked) but if I get another resolution, then it crash...

So I though in creating a xml with percents of the actual resolution of the screen, so it can be compatible with all the screens...

But thoughting, what can I do with the textSize, for example? How can I make it compatible?

I need some advice... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using Relative layout is a better option
Use **dp** - density independent pixels for UI components and **sp** for Text sizes

sp

Scale-independent Pixels - this is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for both the screen density and user's preference.

Comment: And how exactly dp works? If I have a screen with 1024x600 resolution, and I want to create a layout with the 25% of the weight... I would put 150px, but how much in dp? If I put dp's, works well int he eclipse visor, but it doesn't go well in the mobile... thanks